# how to generate a large square binary matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary

i need to generate a large square binary sparse matrix in MATLAB (about 100k x 100k). but i get the "out of memory" error.
Can anybody help?

Comment: http://downloadmoreram.com

Answer (score 2):

A `100,000 x 100,000` matrix contains `10,000,000,000` doubles. At 8 bytes each, that's `80,000,000,000` bytes, i.e. about `74.5058 Gb`.

I seriously doubt you have 80Gb of RAM (let alone, allocated only to matlab), so presumably you'll have to find another way to process your data in chunks.

---

**EDIT** Apologies, I only just noticed the *sparse* bit.

If you try to initialise your sparse matrix as `sparse (zeros( 100000,100000))`, this will fail for the above reason (i.e. you're asking octave / matlab to first store a 75Gb matrix of zeros, and only *then* convert it to a sparse matrix).

Instead, you should initialise your 100,000x100,000 sparse matrix like so:

```
s = sparse(100000,100000);
```

and then proceed to fill in its contents.
Assuming the number of nonzero elements in your sparse matrix is low enough that they can be handled easily with your system's memory, and that you have a way of filling in the necessary values you have in mind without allocating a big bad matrix first, then this should work fine.

Have a look at the `sparse` function for other ways of initialising a sparse matrix from data.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the size of the swap file of your system.

Comment: can you explain how?

Comment: Do you have windows?

Comment: WinLogo+R -> sysdm.cpl -> Advanced -> Performance Settings -> Advanced 
and there you can change the virtual memory file paging.